# Strange behavior with the generated JAR and EXE

Tags: java, path, nullpointerexception, executable

I'm using Jar2EXE to generate my EXE files that running on windows without java installed, in my java desktop application i have to upload a file to a dedicated FTP server, the file is in the same Dir where the Jar is running.. previously i have some probems to get the current path of the jar, then i solve this issue with this line:

```
pathToFile = new File(FtpUploder.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).getParent()+"\\File.doc";
```

I set the jar + File.doc in the same Dir anywhere and its work.

The problem when i generate my exe, the previous line throw NullpointerException then i surrounded it whith try/catch like this:

```
 try{
         pathToFile = new File(FtpUploder.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).getParent()+"\\File.doc"; 
         }
         catch(NullPointerException e)
         {
             pathToFile = "C:\\File.doc";
             System.out.println("path is null ! lets see the new path : pathToFile ="+pathToFile );
         }
```

the strange problem that is the file is successfully uploaded from "C:\File.doc" , so why its doesn't work when i set a dynamic path ?

PS: any help will be appreciated(I'm sorry for my english).

Comment: If the DOC file has become an [embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) by this stage, using that simple formula will fail.  It will probably need to be extracted out of a Jar by URL.  Also, it seems odd that an app. is uploading a `File.doc` that it apparently creates.  How does that come about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within generated exe file, you can simply call `System.getProperty("application.home")` to get the path of generated exe file.

Please refer to http://www.jar2exe.com/createdexe/integrate , in the "Overview".